# subplots in MatLab

Tags: matlab

I use a loop to generate different images that I then collect into a figure with each image as a subplot. I do this for several different iterations of the loop and set the background for each figure to be a certain color, say red as in the example below - which works fine except the last iteration still has a default gray color - how do I change that?

```
set(gcf,'Color','red')
```

Also... kind of related: within the loop how do you make a figure that is separate from the others? So for example

```
figure(i)
subplot etc.
```

How would I then make a totally different figure for each iteration if that makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

To create a new figure, you do not have to call `figure` with an argument. `fh = figure;` creates a new figure and captures the figure handle in the variable `fh`. You can then use `fh` to change the figure's properties, e.g. `set(fh,'Color','red')`. Of course, if there's no need to only set the figure's color at the end of the loop, you can set it when you create the figure, like so: `fh = figure('color','red');`.